# Custom notification interval

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I am building an app in FireMonkey under Rad Studio XE8.

I would like to have custom intervals on my notifications (FMX.Notification).

However notification repeats can only be set to certain intervals.

```
TRepeatInterval = (None, Second, Minute, Hour, Day, Week, Weekday, Month, Quarter, Year, Era);
```

If i whant to  fire each 15 minutes, would I really need to create four notification (at 0 , 15, 30, 45 minutes) and repeat them every hour with TRepeatInterval(4)?

Comment: The tag is delphi-xe8, I added it

Comment: Yeah I tried to add it myself, but stack overflow said I needed 15k points to use that tag.

Comment: No, you tried to add a new tag, perhaps `xe8`. And you can't do that. You don't have the rep needed to create tags. The tag I used is `delphi-xe8` and has been in existence for a long time. You could have used that tag. So, I'm just trying to let you know the convention for delphi versions tags. They are all of that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Notification.TNotification.RepeatInterval) for `FMX.Notification.TNotification.RepeatInterval` says, with my emphasis:

> If you want to set a custom interval, like for example 30 minutes, you **need to create two notifications** setting a scheduled difference of 30 minutes with FireDate and **set the repeat interval of both notifications to an hour**.

You're guessing right. You would need to create four notification and repeat them every hour.

---

*OP told in the comments, that he used following code, in the end. I included it in my answer to improve readability of his given information.*

```
//Repeat very 5 minutes
//Create 12 notifications fireing every hour with 5 minute intervals Notification.RepeatInterval := TRepeatInterval.Hour;
for I := 0 to 11 do
begin
  Notification.FireDate := Notification.FireDate + EncodeTime(0,(I*5),0,0);
  ANotificationcenter.ScheduleNotification(Notification);
end;
```

Comment: The code I finally used.
`//Repeat very 5 minutes

          //Create 12 notifications fireing every hour with 5 minute intervals

          Notification.RepeatInterval := TRepeatInterval.Hour;
          for I := 1 to 12 do
            begin
            Notification.FireDate := Notification.FireDate + EncodeTime(0,(I*5),0,0);
            ANotificationcenter.ScheduleNotification(Notification);
            end;
          end;`

Comment: I included your code in my answer for better readability. Hope, that's OK.

Comment: Thats verry ok. I just saw that that range in the for loop will cause errors in EncodeTime, should be 0-11.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to René Hoffmann's answer

The reason why you can only use those Repeat intervals is because you cannot set custom repeat intervals with iOS,
because it uses the its `UILocalNotification` object and its *RepeatInterval* requires a `NSCalendarUnit` which is a enumerated type.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval

but Android on the otherhand, if you wanted to make a repeating notification you could use the `AlarmManager.setRepeating` method
so if you wanted to make the native repeating Notification that would work for Android you could do this:

`TNotification` resides in `System.Notification`
Add a property to it:

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    RepeatIntervalinMills : Integer;
{$ENDIF}
```

In `TNotification.Create` just give it a default value

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  RepeatIntervalinMills := 0;
{$ENDIF}
```

Now we need to add the native Android method to set a repeating notification, to do this you need to navigate to `System.Android.Notification`

find `TNotificationCenterAndroid.DoScheduleNotification` and now just need to add some code, so that if you didn't specify a RepeatIntervalinMills only the standard Notification is created:

```
begin
  if not ANotification.Name.IsEmpty and FExternalStore.Contains(ANotification.Name) then
    CancelNotification(ANotification.Name);

  ID := TGeneratorUniqueID.GenerateID;
  PendingIntent := CreateNotificationAlarmIntent(ID);
  FExternalStore.SaveNotification(ANotification, ID);

  if ANotification.RepeatIntervalinMills <> 0 then
  begin
      TAndroidHelper.AlarmManager.setRepeating(TJAlarmManager.JavaClass.RTC_WAKEUP, DateTimeLocalToUnixMSecGMT(ANotification.FireDate),
    ANotification.RepeatIntervalinMills,PendingIntent);
  end
  else
  TAndroidHelper.AlarmManager.&set(TJAlarmManager.JavaClass.RTC_WAKEUP, DateTimeLocalToUnixMSecGMT(ANotification.FireDate),
    PendingIntent);
end;
```

Now when you create your Notification :

```
MyNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
    try
        MyNotification.Name := 'MyNotification';
        MyNotification.AlertBody := 'Hello!';
        {$IFDEF IOS}
       //Repeat very 5 minutes
       //Create 12 notifications fireing every hour with 5 minute intervals                    Notification.RepeatInterval := TRepeatInterval.Hour;
       for I := 0 to 11 do
       begin
           Notification.FireDate := Notification.FireDate + EncodeTime(0,(I*5),0,0);
           ANotificationcenter.ScheduleNotification(Notification);
       end;
        {$ENDIF}
        {$IFDEF ANDROID}
        MyNotification.FireDate := IncMinute(Now,5);
        MyNotification.RepeatIntervalinMills := 300000; //Now you can specify your Custom Android Repeat interval
        NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
        {$ENDIF}
    finally
        MyNotification.DisposeOf;
    end;
```

This will create a notfication that will fire in 5 mins and will repeat every 5mins