# Delphi Android service was stopped after closing the android application

Tags: android, delphi, android-service, pascal

I have used Delphi 12 for developing Android application and I'm trying to Service which needs to runs in the background to receive the frequent messages from Server using TCP sockets to displays the notifications. But, the service is deactivated / closed after the main process application is closed.

Below, the code is mentioned the code to start the service :

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonServiceStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ServiceIntent: JIntent;
begin
  ServiceIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  ServiceIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context, StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.MyService'));
  TAndroidHelper.Context.startService(ServiceIntent);
end;
```

and also, I have added the following service information in **AndroidManifest.template.xml** :

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="MyService"
  android:process=":remote" android:name="com.embarcadero.services.MyService">
</service>
```

Code in Service:

```
function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;
```

I have tried to use this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894119/when-the-application-is-closed-the-android-local-service-was-stopped), but not able to compile.

And tried to implement the Sleep in Android Start command / run the thread, still the android service is getting closed.

Do, I need to mentioned the different flag for starting the service or do I need to add additional code to run the service all the time or can we restart the service once it's destroyed and how to handle the code in Destroy event?

Comment: It would help to describe what you're actually trying to achieve overall, because background execution is heavily guarded in Android. If the app is to receive messages from a server, have you considered using push notifications?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to receive the message from Server using TCP sockets in Android service and display the notification. And it was similar to Watsapp notification service which always runs in backround.

Comment: WhatsApp very likely uses push notifications

Comment: Which component I need to use to implement this and is it free or pay to use?